# Multi-level Survey Weighting

Tags: survey, survey-weights

I'm trying to run a multi-level logistic regression using survey weights on my observations using PROC GLIMMIX. However, I only have weights for those individuals that completed the survey, and no weights on those that did not do the survey. My binary response variable is 1=completed survey, versus 0=did not complete survey. Does such an analysis make sense, i.e. is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Weights are used when you want to generalize to the underlying population. The analysis of response/nonresponse process is basically an analysis of how well **your particular protocol** worked. As such, you are analyzing your existing full sample of respondents and nonrespondents, and you are not trying to generalize. So you don't need weights, and can/should run this as an i.i.d. regression.

I talked a little bit about this in http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118594629.ch29/summary.